# what are chaneg need to be done in pom.xml file for migrating from tomcat 7 to tomcat 8?

Tags: tomcat

what are changes need to be done in file like pon.xml in terms of dependencies and in any other file.I am  using java 8 and Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers Version: Mars Release (4.5.0).

Comment: Are you just asking for a web application (then the answer would be: none) or are you using an embedded Tomcat?

Comment: using embedded tomcat, and what is there in NIO and some idea about  UTF encoding changes. i m upgrading my existing tomcat 7 to 8. so i need to know what are the benefits and how i ll get